# Challenge login, Basic Authentication

Tags: jetty, basic-authentication, embedded-jetty

I'm using jetty 9, embedded.

I want to send a challenge when a username doesn't exist in my properties file.

I have extended the BasicAuthenticator class to catch the Exception normally thrown when a username doesn't exist. I can't see how to then after challenge the user with a login again.

```
public class MyBasicAuthenticator extends BasicAuthenticator{
    @Override
    public Authentication validateRequest(ServletRequest req,
        ServletResponse res, boolean mandatory)
    {
        Authentication authentication = null;
        try{
            authentication = super.validateRequest(req,res,mandatory);
            return authentication;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Authentication.SEND_FAILURE;
        } 
    }
```

Authentication.SEND_FAILURE prevents the ErrorHandler being called, but it just loads a blank page. SEND_FAILURE comes from the Authentication interface.

JavaDoc: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/security/authentication/BasicAuthenticator.html

According to the answer to this question Jetty6 had a send challenge method, Jetty9 doesn't.
[Jetty UserRealm redirect on 3th failed login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309261/jetty-userrealm-redirect-on-3th-failed-login)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Basic Auth issue.

```
try {
        authentication = super.validateRequest(req, res, mandatory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try{
            HttpServletResponse r = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            r.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            r.setStatus(401);
            } catch(Exception ew){}
        authentication = Authentication.SEND_FAILURE;
    }
```

Return 401 and a http header that includes "WWW-Authenticate":"Basic"

Authentication.SEND_FAILURE prevents an exception further down the handler chain.